# How to get logged on user details in spring-boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

How can i access the logged in user details in spring-boot application which is configured with Oauth2.

i tried using the below method but it's returning null.

```
public Authentication getLoggedInUserDetails() {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();


        System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

        return auth;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using jwt tokens?

Comment: no, i'm using oauth tokens.

Answer (score 1):

If user is logged in, then:

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)auth.getPrincipal();
userDetails.getUsername();
userDetails.getAuthorities();
userDetails.getPassword();
```

Comment: Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); returning null.

Comment: hi @ManikantaB ,
if getAuthentication() returns null that mean that user is not logged in.
Is it possible to see more code and stack?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String getDashboard(Model model) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
    model.addAttribute("user", userDetails.getUsername());
    return "/test";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks